# Replacing outlier values with NaN in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nan, outliers

I have an n x m data matrix with n samples and m measurements per sample. I'm dealing with data from mass spectrometry, measuring the concentration of different metabolites. Each column is the concentrations of a single metabolite. The rows are the samples. Some of the samples have a few metabolite measurements that are much higher than the rest of the samples.

I want to find these outlier values, and replace them with NaN. Is there a way to do this automatically, maybe by looking for values higher than X column SDs and making them NaN? I have found relevant questions for R and Python, but not for MATLAB.

Addendum: dfri's solution worked perfectly for me. However, I couldn't use the column SD as a cutoff-measure, because the outliers made the SD so large that the outlier values were still within the threshold (they were 10 000 times larger than the rest). I ended up using 100 x the column median as a threshold for removal.

Comment: Can you provide some example data? Is the metabolite column just one column? And if there is an outlier in that column do you want to just make the number `NaN` or the whole row? Or so you want to do this per column? Also you mention looking for x standard deviations (I assume above the mean) but you might rather consider using an [interquartile range](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Interquartile_range#/Interquartile_range_and_outliers) based method

Comment: @dfri answer is pretty allright. However you should pay attention when considering outliers. The critical parameter (of course) is the threshold. How such values are distributed? If you can answer this question, the threshold setup is rather easy. A common example/rule-of-thumb is the following: if your data has a Gaussian distribution, set the threshold as 3 times the standard deviation.

Comment: Each column represents a single metabolite. I want to make the single measurement (matrix cell) NaN, not the entire column or row.

Answer (score 4):

You can compare elements in your data for some threshold to identify your outliers, and use the resulting indices to replace outlier values by `NaN`. E.g.

```
data = randi(4,5); %// values in {1, 2, 3, 4}
threshold = 3;     %// decide upon your threshold
data(data > threshold) = NaN

data =

   NaN     3   NaN     2     2
     3     1     3     2     2
     2     2     2   NaN     3
     3     1   NaN   NaN     3
     1     1     1     1   NaN
```

---

If you want to replace outliers w.r.t. some threshold column per column, you can make use of e.g. `bsxfun` (thanks @Dan):

```
data = randi(4,5) %// values in {1, 2, 3, 4}
threshold = mean(data)+1*std(data) %// per column
data(bsxfun(@(x, y) x > y, data, threshold)) = NaN

%// example:

threshold =

    4.7416    3.7416    4.0000    2.8954    1.9477

data =

     4     3     2   NaN   NaN
     4   NaN     3     1     1
     1     3     4     1   NaN
     4     1     4     1     1
     4     1     2   NaN     1
```

Note that the most important (non-matlab-technical) part in your case, as mentioned by @Dan in his comments above, is to decide upon how you create your threshold values for each of the columns. The simple thresholds in the example above has only been included to show the technical aspects of how to "remove" outliers (set to `NaN`) given an array of thresholds for the columns.

Comment: This doesn't make use of `find` ;)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there a way to have a different threshold for each column, by e.g. defining it in terms of the column SD?

Comment: @dfri you should use `bsxfun` rather than `arrayfun` for this. With `bsxfun` you can naturally extend your first method to find the indexes for the entire matrix but have your threshold as a row vector (i.e. different thresholds per column) rather than a scalar.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the tip, that sounds more reasonable, I'll look into it after lunch unless someone beats me to it. Thanks!

Comment: @TorfinnStøveMadssen `@(x,y) ...` defines an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) `...` over `x` and `y`; compare e.g. with lambdas in Python. This is a valid first argument to [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which takes a function handle as its first argument, with 2nd and 3rd argument applied as values `x` and `y`, element-wise, to the anonymous function (with singleton expansion enabled, hence expanding the column vector `threshold` along the (`4`) rows of `data`).

Comment: @TorfinnStøveMadssen without seeing your code it's hard to tell: the _method_ above is general, however you application of it might yield unexpected results for other reasons. I mention again: take care when choosing your threshold: also take care that threshold should be a _row vector_ and not a column vector. Finally, if you use my simple threshold example above (which you probably shouldn't: choosing a threshold is up to you w.r.t. your specific data): note that if you have a single huge value, then it will push up the mean which means the threshold itself will be large for such a column.

Comment: @dfri I was too hasty in asking. I figured out what had gone wrong, and it had nothing to do with your code. I'm now certain it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @TorfinnStøveMadssen Happy to help.